# Reading dot files with graphviz package in haskell

Tags: haskell, layout, graphviz, dot

For a program i have to reformat a dot file in Haskell to adjust the layout of its tree/content. I decided to use https://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz-2999.20.1.0/docs/Data-GraphViz.html , but i cant find simple tutorials and the documentation confuses me, namely:

1 . It contains a function: *dotToGraph*, which reads: "A pseudo-inverse to graphToDot; "pseudo" in the sense that the original node and edge labels aren't able to be reconstructed."

I do need to retain the names of the nodes and edges, which i suppose are the labels mentioned here? but it seems weird that it cannot do this. It also does not take in a file name or string for the dot text, so i assume this is the wrong function.

2 . There also seems to be a *parseDot* function/class that comes with the package, but i cant find clear documentation for its use. (see: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphviz-2999.20.1.0/docs/Data-GraphViz-Parsing.html#t:ParseDot)

Can you recommend me a simple overview/summary/online example for doing this? Should i be using a different function? I have only recently started using Haskell, so the package documentation is sometimes difficult to decipher for me.

It would help a great deal, thanks!

Comment: The doc says "you should not be using this module; rather, it is here for informative/documentative reasons. If you want to parse a DotRepr, you should use parseDotGraph rather than its ParseDot instance." The former says " Parse a limited subset of the Dot language to form an instance of DotRepr"

Comment: ahhh wow, i'm embarrassed i missed that. Thanks a lot, sometimes all you need is a second pair of eyes!